# Cq Parsys with a Parsys

Tags: aem

I would like to create a component which is a parsys and can hold some specific components only. I have copied the parsys component from the foundation, and create a new component drag-drop-parsys, but when I drag it on the page, that on the parsys, I can see the green-surronding bar for "drag-drop-parsys". Can some one please let me know what should I do. 
    Parsys with in Parsys (drag-drop-parsys) and which can hold specific components.

Thanks for all your help.

-MG

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify why you are created an entirely new paragraph system? Generally to limit certain components to a certain parsys, you would use the "Design", a configuration that specifies exactly that. You specify in the design that X, Y, and Z components (or component groups) are available in any parsys named "your parsys name" per page component.

Here's the documentation:
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/designer.html

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a NEW component "my-parsys" that inherits from the system parsys component.  Then the new component could restrict allowedChildren to the desired set of draggable components.  Theoretically, this wouldn't require any JSP's - just the settings around your draggable parsys.

NOTE: generally, it doesn't make sense to drag a parsys directly into another parsys - that is just nesting lists of components.  However, we have created "wrapper" components that themselves may have their own parsys for components inside themselves.